# Are there other ways to delete HTML columns besides the Javascript I'm using that's not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my HTML & Javascript code is not working like it is in this snippet. I want to remove 3 columns: the first, skip the next 2, then remove the following 2; leaving only 3 columns. In the AMS the first column is completely removed, then the next column removes the first 2 rows and that's it. It seems the loop stops there and I'm scratching my head.

A generalized form of my code is in the snippet below, but of course there are values of all sorts in the AMS HTML table on the site. I'm still novice to Javascript, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to code it that may magically fix this issue.

```html
<table id="TC_Users" border=1 cellpadding=5>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>r0 h0</th>
  <th>r0 h1</th>
  <th>r0 h2</th>
  <th>r0 h3</th>
  <th>r0 h4</th>
  <th>r0 h5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r1 c0</td>
  <td>r1 c1</td>
  <td>r1 c2</td>
  <td>r1 c3</td>
  <td>r1 c4</td>
  <td>r1 c5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r2 c0</td>
  <td>r2 c1</td>
  <td>r2 c2</td>
  <td>r2 c3</td>
  <td>r2 c4</td>
  <td>r2 c5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
//I'm forced to put the javascript in <script> tags. 
//Also, the 'if' statement is {parsing} on one side of the "Other" formula 
if ("Other" == "Other") {
var tbl = document.getElementById("TC_Users");
var rw = tbl.rows;
var iA = 0;  for (var j = 0; j < rw.length; j++)  {  rw[j].deleteCell(iA);  } 
var iB = 2;  for (var j = 0; j < rw.length; j++)  {  rw[j].deleteCell(iB);  } 
var iC = 2;  for (var j = 0; j < rw.length; j++)  {  rw[j].deleteCell(iC);  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your existing code appears to be working as intended.

Comment: Yes, it appears. I'm working around code I cannot access in my AMS and something is breaking it. My hope was to find a few other ways to code with the same results.

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm forced to put code AFTER the table in <script> tags. The edit made to my code changes the scenario. I'm putting it back.

Comment: It's still working after your revert.    Sounds like the issue is that your code is running before the DOM renders.  Wrap your js in a `window.onload` and you should be all set (and as a bonus won't need to worry about whether the script comes before the html or not anymore.)

Comment: I think the issue was my method was clashing with other code in the real table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with querySelectorAll, couple selectors, and a loop.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#TC_Users tr > *:first-child, #TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(3), #TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(4) ')
cells.forEach(function(cell){
  cell.remove();
});
```

```html
<table id="TC_Users" border=1 cellpadding=5>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>r0 h0</th>
  <th>r0 h1</th>
  <th>r0 h2</th>
  <th>r0 h3</th>
  <th>r0 h4</th>
  <th>r0 h5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r1 c0</td>
  <td>r1 c1</td>
  <td>r1 c2</td>
  <td>r1 c3</td>
  <td>r1 c4</td>
  <td>r1 c5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r2 c0</td>
  <td>r2 c1</td>
  <td>r2 c2</td>
  <td>r2 c3</td>
  <td>r2 c4</td>
  <td>r2 c5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You could also just do it with CSS

```css
#TC_Users tr > *:first-child,
#TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(3),
#TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="TC_Users" border=1 cellpadding=5>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>r0 h0</th>
  <th>r0 h1</th>
  <th>r0 h2</th>
  <th>r0 h3</th>
  <th>r0 h4</th>
  <th>r0 h5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r1 c0</td>
  <td>r1 c1</td>
  <td>r1 c2</td>
  <td>r1 c3</td>
  <td>r1 c4</td>
  <td>r1 c5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>r2 c0</td>
  <td>r2 c1</td>
  <td>r2 c2</td>
  <td>r2 c3</td>
  <td>r2 c4</td>
  <td>r2 c5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Technically, it's exactly the answer I wanted, other ways to code. You even read my mind on hoping for a CSS trick too. However, the Javascript and CSS both broke the whole page, like it's applying to everything... My code sits in a content block below the table, so Javascript typically works well in these situations since it will load after. My table has an ID and when I add that before the CSS (#TC_Users ...) it doesn't completely break the page, but there are still tables outside of the target effected. I'll see what else I can do with what you provided... Thanks!

Comment: well you would need to change the selector to only alter the table you want it to apply to.So just add #TC_Users in front of it

Comment: I included a table ID. I'm not sure how to do what you are saying, but I'll research what you provided and see what I can find unless you make an edit to show me. Thanks.

Comment: I altered the code, it is just the basic css selector

Comment: Thanks, both worked, but since I need to evaluate a parse value I'm going with the Javascript. Btw, I did have to up the 'nth' numbers by one for the real table. Here's the final result: <script>
if ("Other" == "Other") {
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#TC_Users tr > *:first-child, #TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(4), #TC_Users tr > *:nth-child(5) ')
cells.forEach(function(cell){cell.remove();});
}
</script>